# Blockchain : To interact with it, is it necessary to install a client application?

Tags: networking, transactions, p2p, blockchain

I'm a developer and I'm interested in blockchain technology. 
I only have a few knowledges of networking, including peer to peer P2P. 
On the internet, I can't find the answer for this question : Must I use a client application to interact with a blockchain (to perform transactions & to participate in the construction of the blockchain).
If there's no need, how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blockchain is not singular. There might be differet number of blockchain in this world.
Coming to your question, if you want to develop an app/learn the technology it will be better to get yourself acquianted with Ethereum and some basic Blockchain concepts. There is a full length course available on Coursera on Blockchain and cryptocurrency. I would suggest you to finish that first and then move to development.

Answer (score 1):

Think of all these different blockchains as communication protocols. At their heart, that is all Ethereum and Bitcoin are - a suite of specifications as to how peers should talk to each other. Thus, "interacting" with a blockchain is essentially establishing communication with other peers and then exchanging information with them. Well, that only entails following the protocol of that blockchain, because otherwise the peers will disregard you. You can do that by either coding your own software against the specifications, or downloading a pre made client that blockchain makers typically provide.